# Video Game where you control a woman (an acrobat?) in early 1900s Europe who can interact with shadows

Tags: story-identification, video-games

I suspect that I'm just shy from finding this. I saw a review of the game on YouTube a few years ago, which lauded it for its innovative mechanics, but I think commented that it was a bit too short, and the platforming a bit finicky (always a problem with 3d platformers). The game follows a young boy, I'm pretty sure in Europe, probably France, likely during World War II. His mother works in a bar, and I think his father is a soldier, so he's left in his room for long amounts of time. I think he can change places with the primary person that you control, a female acrobat, who can interact with shadows as if they were real objects, which led to much of the game being puzzles where you move objects and light sources to create the shadows necessary for her to get to a location to throw a switch to allow the boy to move.

I think the game's title may have started with a C, but all that's coming to mind is *Control*.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

As I was writing the last sentence of my question, another "C" title came to mind, *[Contrast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contrast_(video_game))*.

> The game is set in a noir atmosphere aesthetically inspired by Belle Epoque and Art Nouveau. The player must solve puzzles that require movement between the physical world, which is represented as 3D, and shadows, which are represented as 2D. The player may sometimes manipulate different light sources in the 3D world (spotlights, film projectors, etc.) to create the shadow paths that reach into new areas; "collectibles", available through game-play, offer insight into the game's characters and the world in which they live. The goal of the game is exploration and discovery through problem solving.
>
> Dawn and Didi are the two characters who appear as full 3D figures. The player controls Dawn, an imaginary friend, who is able to manifest as a three-dimensional shadow. Dawn is able to jump between two shadows, no matter how far apart they are. Almost all other characters appear as shadows against the visual walls, but they still interact with the world as though they are "real."

....

> The game opens with Didi's invisible friend Dawn entering her room before Didi's mother puts her to bed before the mother leaves for the evening to sing at a local nightclub. Didi sneaks out of her house to watch her mother's performance, and ends up eavesdropping on her father meeting her mother, telling her mother about his newest plan to strike it rich, which is to open a circus....

Apparently I misremembered the gender of Didi.

### Game Trailer